# Tomcat server doesn't set secure flag on session id

Tags: ssl, http, cookies, apache

I read that in Tomcat > 6 the secure flag gets set automatically on JSESSIONID cookie. Now I've just looked at the responses I got and the secure flag is not set. The installed version is 7. How come that this can happen and how can I remediate this issue?